# artefact in noise texture combined with vector-map

Tags: texturing, vector-mapping

I have some problem with a noise texture in my shader for anodised aluminium. I use the noise texture to get nice structure for the aluminium. Everything fine so far, excepting the plane parallel to XY.

[image: result with structure I want and problem in plane parallel to XY]

This is my shader-setup we use:

[image: shader for color etc.]

[image: shader with vector map and noise texture for structure]

I'm new to Blender so I have no idea how to solve the problem.
Can someone help me to get the structure also on the planes parallel to XY?

Here is a minimal example with the problem:
[image]